# Two custom loops on same page in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, loops, foreach, while-loop, pagination

I wasn't able to find anything on here, so I am bringing this question to you. The following code does mainly what I want, only the page-cycle doesn't work: When I want to navigate to older posts, the page that is seen displays the same new posts again. How do I do this properly?

So index.php has two loops:

```
<?php
  $args = array( 'numberposts' => 1, 
    'post_status'=>"publish",
    'post_type'=>"post",
    'orderby'=>"post_date");
  $postslist = get_posts( $args );
  foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); 
?>

  // regular post html with wp tags

<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php
  query_posts('posts_per_page=12&offset=1');
  if (have_posts()) : ?>

<h3>Headline</h3>

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

  // regular html with wp tags for these posts (teasers, with the_excerpt)

  <?php endwhile; ?>

    <div class="navigation">
      <span class="nextlink"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older', 0 ); ?></span>
      <span class="previouslink"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer' ); ?></span>
    </div>

    <?php else : ?>

    <h3><?php _e('Nothing found'); ?></h3>

  <?php endif; ?>
```

Here is the explanation: One visits the blog: The most recent blog post is displayed in full length in one block, the 12 older posts (excluding the first one with `offset`, so 2–13) are displayed in another block with content teasers and a next-previous-navigation at the bottom to display post teasers 14–25 and so on. (The problem: it's always 2–13)

**// Edit: Code in response to the top answer, now the full code of the index.php. Notice, that the HTML has changed, since I have used normalized HTML, since it should usually not matter. This times it's the actual code.**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="box blog-block">
  <?php
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => 1, 'post_status'=>"publish",'post_type'=>"post",'orderby'=>"post_date");
    $postslist = get_posts( $args );
     foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
  <span class="head"><?php the_time('j. F Y') ?></span>
  <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
  <div class="entry">
    <?php global $more;
          $more = 1;
          the_content();
    ?>
    <p class="author"><?php the_author(); ?></p>
    <p><a class="more-link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>#respond" title="<?php the_title();?>">Kommentieren</a>
  </div>

    <?php endforeach;
    wp_reset_postdata(); /* 1. reset post data */
    ?>

</div>

<div class="box" id="recentposts">

  <?php

  $paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;

  $display_count = 12;
  $excluded_count = 1;        
  $offset = ( ($paged-1) * $display_count ) + $excluded_count;

  $args = array(
      'post_status'=>"publish",
      'post_type'=>"post",
      'orderby'=>"post_date",
      'posts_per_page' => $display_count,
      'offset' => $offset,
      'paged' => $paged
  );

  $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
  if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

  <h3>Bisherige Artikel</h3>

  <div class="recentpostsmasonry">

  <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

    <div <?php post_class('halb'); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
      <span class="head"><?php the_time('j. F Y') ?></span>
      <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
      <div class="entry">
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        <p class="more-link"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Weiterlesen ...</a></p>
        <p class="comments"><?php edit_post_link(__('Bearbeiten'), '', ' | '); ?> <?php comments_popup_link(__('Schreib den ersten Kommentar'), __('Ein Kommentar'), __('% Kommentare'), '', __('') ); ?></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

  </div>

  <div class="navigation">
    <span class="nextlink" title="Ältere Einträge"><?php next_posts_link( '«', 0 ); ?></span>
    <span class="previouslink" title="Jüngere Einträge"><?php previous_posts_link( '»' ); ?></span>
  </div>

  <?php else : ?>

  <h3><?php _e('Nichts gefunden :('); ?></h3>

  <?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

I am trying out this code now (14.10.17), but it doesn't add functioning page navigation...:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="box blog-block">
  <?php
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => 1, 'post_status'=>"publish",'post_type'=>"post",'orderby'=>"post_date");
    $postslist = get_posts( $args );
     foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
  <span class="head"><?php the_time('j. F Y') ?></span>
  <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
  <div class="entry">
    <?php global $more;
          $more = 1;
          the_content();
    ?>
    <p class="author"><?php the_author(); ?></p>
    <p><a class="more-link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>#respond" title="<?php the_title();?>">Kommentieren</a>
  </div>

    <?php endforeach;
    wp_reset_postdata(); /* 1. reset post data */
    ?>

</div>

<div class="box" id="recentposts">

  <?php

  $paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;

  $display_count = 12;
  $excluded_count = 1;
  $offset = ( ($paged-1) * $display_count ) + $excluded_count;

  $args = array(
      'post_status'=>"publish",
      'post_type'=>"post",
      'orderby'=>"post_date",
      'posts_per_page' => $display_count,
      'offset' => $offset,
      'paged' => $paged
  );

  $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
  if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>



  <h3>Bisherige Artikel</h3>

  <div class="recentpostsmasonry">

  <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

    <div <?php post_class('halb'); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
      <span class="head"><?php the_time('j. F Y') ?></span>
      <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
      <div class="entry">
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        <p class="more-link"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Weiterlesen ...</a></p>
        <p class="comments"><?php edit_post_link(__('Bearbeiten'), '', ' | '); ?> <?php comments_popup_link(__('Schreib den ersten Kommentar'), __('Ein Kommentar'), __('% Kommentare'), '', __('') ); ?></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

  </div>

  <div class="navigation">
    <span class="nextlink" title="Ältere Einträge"><?php next_posts_link( '«', 0 ); ?></span>
    <span class="previouslink" title="Jüngere Einträge"><?php previous_posts_link( '»' ); ?></span>
  </div>

  <?php else : ?>

  <h3><?php _e('Nichts gefunden :('); ?></h3>

  <?php endif; ?>

</div>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

New:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="box blog-block">
  <?php
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => 1, 'post_status'=>"publish",'post_type'=>"post",'orderby'=>"post_date");
    $postslist = get_posts( $args );
     foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
  <span class="head"><?php the_time('j. F Y') ?></span>
  <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
  <div class="entry">
    <?php global $more;
          $more = 1;
          the_content();
    ?>
    <p class="author"><?php the_author(); ?></p>
    <p><a class="more-link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>#respond" title="<?php the_title();?>">Kommentieren</a>
  </div>

    <?php endforeach;
    wp_reset_postdata(); /* 1. reset post data */
    ?>

</div>

<div class="box" id="recentposts">

  <?php

  $paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;

  $display_count = 12;
  $excluded_count = 1;
  $offset = ( ($paged-1) * $display_count ) + $excluded_count;

  $args = array(
      'post_status'=>"publish",
      'post_type'=>"post",
      'orderby'=>"post_date",
      'posts_per_page' => $display_count,
      'offset' => $offset,
      'paged' => $paged
  );

  $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
  if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>



  <h3>Bisherige Artikel</h3>

  <div class="recentpostsmasonry">

  <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

    <div <?php post_class('halb'); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
      <span class="head"><?php the_time('j. F Y') ?></span>
      <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
      <div class="entry">
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        <p class="more-link"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Weiterlesen ...</a></p>
        <p class="comments"><?php edit_post_link(__('Bearbeiten'), '', ' | '); ?> <?php comments_popup_link(__('Schreib den ersten Kommentar'), __('Ein Kommentar'), __('% Kommentare'), '', __('') ); ?></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

  </div>

  <div class="navigation">
    <span class="nextlink" title="Ältere Einträge"><?php next_posts_link( '«', $the_query->max_num_pages ); ?></span>
    <span class="previouslink" title="Jüngere Einträge"><?php previous_posts_link( '»' ); ?></span>
  </div>

  <?php else : ?>

  <h3><?php _e('Nichts gefunden :('); ?></h3>

  <?php endif; ?>

</div>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't set up paging, so your query always thinks its on page 1.

Also according to the [WP Developer Resources](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/) , you shouldn't use `query_posts`- use `WP_Query` or `pre_get_posts` instead, so I'm using WP_Query below to do your 2nd query.

Note that I've assumed you are using this on a static homepage, but I've added the change required for a custom page in comments.

```
<?php
  $args = array( 'numberposts' => 1, 
    'post_status'=>"publish",
    'post_type'=>"post",
    'orderby'=>"post_date");
  $postslist = get_posts( $args );
  foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); 
?>

  // regular post html with wp tags

<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata(); /* 1. reset post data */
?>

<?php
/* Set up your pagination - $paged will contain the current page, telling WP_Query which post to start with (e.g. #13 on page 2) */
$paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;

/*  NOTE: if this is NOT on a static page
get the 'paged' query var instead of 'page', i.e.:
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
*/

$display_count = 12; /* variable for the number of posts per page */
$excluded_count = 1; /* the number of posts excluded from the start position */

/* Calculate the offset, i.e. the post number to start the page with
   Normally this is calculated by: ($paged-1) * $display_count 
   so we just need to add 1 for the one we excluded */
$offset = ( ($paged-1) * $display_count ) + $excluded_count;

/* set up your new query passing in the page so WP_Query knows what to return */
$args = array(
    'post_status'=>"publish",
    'post_type'=>"post",
    'orderby'=>"post_date",
    'posts_per_page' => $display_count,
    'offset' => $offset,
    'paged' => $paged
);

/* set up your new query */
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <h3>Headline</h3>

    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>    

        // regular html with wp tags for these posts (teasers, with the_excerpt)

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <div class="navigation">
      <span class="nextlink"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older', $the_query->max_num_pages ); ?></span>
      <span class="previouslink"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer' ); ?></span>
    </div>

    <?php else : ?>

    <h3><?php _e('Nothing found'); ?></h3>

<?php endif; ?>
```

The above code is untested, but the basic logic should be right.

**UPDATE:**

[next_posts_link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link) and 
[previous_posts_link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_posts_link) use the global variable `$wp_query` by default, so to make is use your custom query, pass `$custom_query->max_num_pages` into `next_posts_link`, e.g.:

```
<span class="nextlink"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older', $the_query->max_num_pages ); ?></span>
<span class="previouslink"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer' ); ?></span>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Though, the code produces a blank page again. I have checked syntax and I have tried 'page' and 'paged'. (it's for the index.php)...

Comment: @ThomasMaier A blank screen means there's a syntax error in the code. As I said, my code wasn't tested so there could be some basic syntax errors in there. If you can't find them let me know and I'll take a look - I'm goig off line now for a bit :)

Comment: I have added the updated code to my entry here. Thanks! (I will try to fix it myself in the meantime)

Comment: @ThomasMaier In the new code you added to your question, you are missing `get_footer();` at the end. Apart from that it works perfectly for me when I tried in it. Because it was working, I was able to see that I'd made a mistake with the offset, so I've updated my answer. I also updated your new code in your question, so you can just copy & paste it into your index.php.

Comment: Hi there, sorry had a lot going on before I was able to review the problem another time. I posed the new code in the original post for index.php but it doesn't work... Have I not included something from your code? When I use parts of your code from your original answer, the page goes completely blank...

Comment: @ThomasMaier I see you have found whatever caused the blank screen, and now its just the navigation isn't showing. You just need to change your `next_posts_link` to the following: `next_posts_link( 'Older', $the_query->max_num_pages );`. I've updated also update my answer. Let me know if that works for you!

Comment: Hi, I added a new version at the bottom of the original post with the full code in index.php. I changed everything in they way you said I think. Now it goes to page /2/ but not further, and always shows the posts of the first page on either...

Comment: @ThomasMaier Sounds like you're using the wrong paging variable then. As I noted in my answer and the comments in the code, you only use `page` for static home pages and `paged` for everything else. Try changing the  `$paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;` to the version for a non-static page, i.e.  `$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;`

Comment: AWESOME! It works! Almost unbelievable. What one letter can do. Thanks so much!